# Convert currency based on API field in a react Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a widget developed in React where i am showing some cost values, and the currency is based upon a field that is coming from API.
So there is one actual cost which is = 1070. So when, the unit is USD we will show **1.1k$**

this is been done with a function already written

```
export const formatCurrency = (
  value: number,
  symbol: string = 'USD',
  locale: string = 'en-US'
) => {
  return Formatters(locale).number.currency(symbol)(value);
};

export const getSymbolFromCurrency = (currencyCode: string) => {
  const currencySymbolMap: Record<string, string> = {
    USD: '$', // US Dollar
    EUR: '€', // Euro
    CRC: '₡', // Costa Rican Colón
    GBP: '£', // British Pound Sterling
    INR: '₹' // Indian Rupee
  };
  if (typeof currencyCode !== 'string') {
    return undefined;
  }
  const code = currencyCode.toUpperCase();
  return currencySymbolMap[code];
};
```

this function is able to convert the symbols based on unit coming for example "INR" "GBP"
but the values are not getting converted

what locales do i need to add in formatCurrency so that it changes the values automatically since that function takes two arguments  `{formatCurrency(actualCost, costCurrency)}`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDzDP.png)

Comment: What do you mean by _"the values are not getting converted"_? What do you expect to see vs what do you actually see?

Comment: Also, what libraries, if any are you relying on? Where is `Formatters` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear what you're after but in order to represent `1070` as `$1.1k`, you can use the *compact* notation option for [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).

You also don't typically need to provide your own currency symbols, just the currency code.

```js
// I've tried to match `Formatters` to the way you seem to expect to use it
const Formatters = locale => ({
  number: {
    currency: currency => {
      const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
        style: "currency",
        notation: "compact", // 
        currency
      })
      return value => formatter.format(value)
    }
  }
})

// copied as plain JS from your question
const formatCurrency = (
  value,
  symbol = 'USD',
  locale = 'en-US'
) => Formatters(locale).number.currency(symbol)(value)

for (let [ locale, currency ] of [["en-US","USD"],["fr-FR","EUR"],["es-CR","CRC"],["en-GB","GBP"],["hi-IN","INR"]]) {
  console.log(`${currency} (${locale}):`,
    formatCurrency(1070, currency, locale))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: actually the value is getting converted into dollars but i need to change this 


export const formatCurrency = (
  value: number,
  symbol: string = 'USD',
  locale: string = 'en-US'
) => {
  return Formatters(locale).number.currency(symbol)(value);
};

So that if i pass the value and currency then based on that it converts the value

Comment: Suppose i pass formatCurrency(1070,GBP)   so i want it to convert to pounds

Comment: @Anish I'm sorry, I'm not following at all. Your `formatCurrency` function should already work fine. If you want to change how the values are formatted, you'll have to do so in `Formatters`

Comment: i am a little unclear i know but the format currency works fine but it has just USD locales, how to tackle if the currency changes, i tried adding INR locales but the value wasnt correct